# Why is my Focusrite Scarlett 2i4 no longer recognized?

Tags: usb, troubleshooting

Last night, after a year of continued and problem free use, I discovered that my computer no longer detects my Scarlett 2i4. My DAW (Ableton Live 9.1) says that no audio devices are detected and even Windows 8 cannot see it in audio devices.

I am running Windows 8.1 x64

Scarlett connected via original USB cable (no powered hub).

I have tried every USB port on motherboard and switched around the cable.

I have the latest Focusrite drivers and have reinstalled them twice.

Scarlett 2i4 appears in device manager, but not recognized by DAW or Windows > sounds / audio devices.

I also, have tried this on my iMac running OS 10.8, and my ASUS N56VJ laptop running windows 8.1 x64bit, yet the same issue is occurring which seems to worryingly confirm that the issue is, indeed, hardware related.

From the information I have providided, am I correct in thinking that the device is faulty and needs replacing?

Comment: 99% chance of "yes", assuming you already tried replacing the cable.

Comment: Ok, it is in the device manager but not among audio… then among what? But the Debra proposal should be good. I had already some issue with a cable (but an active one).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the original poster in [a comment to an answer](https://superuser.com/questions/746708/why-is-my-focusrite-scarlett-2i4-no-longer-recognized#comment1022281_785003) states, “Thanks David, Unfortunately I replaced the unit, but will remember this if the issue happens again.” So this question is effectively abandoned and “solved” by the purchase of a new device. No way an actual “answer” could ever be provided now.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this exact same problem.

What you have to do is to go to [the driver website.](http://us.focusrite.com/usb-audio-interfaces/scarlett-2i4/downloads) and
to download and install the drivers where it said **Windows XP Only**.

My system is Windows 8 and this solution worked fine for me.
Before I tried the Windows 7/8 drivers but they didn't work.

Comment: Thanks David, Unfortunately I replaced the unit, but will remember this if the issue happens again.

Answer (score -2):

Just reinstall the drivers while USB Scarlet 2i4 is NOT connected. Then restart the PC and after the Windows starts connect the Scarlet 2i4.

This is written in the manual...